# Using post message API of chrome in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, iframe

I am making a chrome extension for a client. The functionality of the extension is that, it adds another private like button to a post. And when someone click that like button, that poster will be notified.

How I worked with it is like that : I have used a Facebook login button, and then to get that user Facebook data. From the Facebook SDK I am getting , user app scope id (the digits key), user-app-scoped-link, user name and gender etc. When a user click that Facebook button, the required data from Facebook is retrieved. From this data, only the name is appeared in the form, and the user is required to fill a form by providing their email and password. You can check it [here](http://bitbaysolutions.com/). When the user click the submit button, the form data and the data retrieved from the Facebook is saved in the database table on my server.

The problem is that, the Facebook SDK code doesn't work in the chrome extension because the extension doesn't allow external scripts. So for that reason I have kept the SDK scripts on the server and made an html page and saved that there as well which you can see in the provided link. To overcome that problem I have used iframe in my extension so it will not detect the scripts loaded externally.

When the data is saved on the table, and as I mentioned that I get an app scoped link from Facebook I display that link right away on that page. Which means that is displayed in an iframe on my extension. And I want to grab that link from that iframe whenever it is loaded in that div element in the iframe. Because I want to work with that link locally in my extension.

Conclusion : Grab the URL or Link from iframe, and that iframe is loading external .html file from server.

**You can check the process on this [Link](http://bitbaysolutions.com/)**

**Below is my iframe code :**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src=jquery.js></script>
</head>

<body>

<iframe src="http://bitbaysolutions.com" id="myFrame" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;border:none;overflow-y:scroll; ">
 
</iframe>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src=script2.js></script>
</html>
```

> With this iframe I want to work in script2.js. I want to get that link displayed in iframe and work with it in local **scripts2.js** file .

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. That URL has not appeared in the box by itself, but your app must have written it into there in the first place. So you must have the information somewhere already.

Comment: it do appear, first when u click the facebook button and then click the submit form by providing random email and pass,  then after submitting a url will appear

Comment: That was not the point. Your script is first requesting this value from the API, only to send it to your server via AJAX, have it returned from there again and put into that box. So if you need the value in your script - then grab it at the point where it gets requested from the API.

Comment: on facebook button click, I get the requested data, and then the username appear in the form, and you provide email and password. By submitting the form the data has been sent through ajax to the server inserted in the table. and at the same time the link is grabbed from that same data and appeared in the frame

Comment: So, what is the actual problem then? You have the value directly after the user performs the Facebook login, you have it after your AJAX request - what more do you need?

Comment: I am getting that url from the script I saved on server, and I want to actually pass that url to a script which is saved locally with me

Comment: From that server script I want to pass it to my local script which is on my local host

Comment: _“I am getting that url from the script I saved on server”_ - not even true ... You are passing this value into your function `saveData` as a parameter named `link`, in which you send it to the server via AJAX, but then you don’t take it from the data the server returned to put it into the box, you are simply using the parameter that was passed to the function. So, again: You _have_ that value in your JS code already.

Comment: let me add the script of server what I did

Comment: What for ...? Looking at your client-side JS code, it is more than clear that you _have_ the value there already.

Comment: I have a script here locally saved on my computer, and the script on server which you are looking at is scoped to the iframe only, it works for the iframe, how can I interact with that script, my local script to get that link

Comment: You are making less and less sense. What iframe? The link you have given as example does not have any iframes.

Comment: I need to pass it locally, I don't need to operate on that link, on server I want to operate on that link locally so that, actually I want to ajaxify that link, in my chrome extension that is not possible from the server because of the origin policy

Comment: I still don’t understand what you are even trying to achieve here. Please describe the whole process in enough detail, so that it becomes understandable.

Comment: Oh god, my mistake, I have saved that index file on the server, and made it show in iframe on my browser extension .html file, so that link basically appears in that iframe scope locally and I want to get that

Comment: And what’s that got to do with any browser extension then?

Comment: let me update the question

Comment: You can check the question now @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for it, 
All you I had to do is; use `window.postMessage(url-I-wanted-to-pass,oringin)` and then trigger the message event on my local file to get that message.